# linking ionic app with google map and locate the searched location based on results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

am developing ionic app,i manage to load a data from json data with a search input,so my problem is to link those place when i searched with google map,and show the marker on the specific place i click after i click,
here is my request in json data

[click here to see the output result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJA0j.png)

```
$scope.preview = false;
  $scope.searchAtms = function(){
    $scope.preview = true;
    console.log("Button works");
    $http.get("https://atmlocate.firebaseio.com/.json").then(function (response) {      
      $scope.map_positions = response.data;


      $scope.object_by_id = $filter('filter')($scope.map_positions.results, {Location: $scope.location });

    });
  };
```

i get that output with tha data,so how can i connect with google map api,and locate those place when i fire a function search_item(item)

```
      <ion-item item-icon-right ng-repeat="item in object_by_id" ng-show="preview" >
        <div class="test" >

          <a class="button icon icon-right  ion-location"  href="location.html"  ng-click="placeMarker(item)">

            {{item.ATM}}
            {{item.Location}}

          </a>

        </div>  
      </ion-item>     
</ion-list>
```

Comment: what  is {{ item.Location}} holding ?

Comment: If you open the image of ui it show details of item.ATM and item.location,but the object also contain latitude and longitude.if I write {{item.lat}} it will show the latitude value

Comment: ok perfect you made the job see how to put marker on map 

http://plnkr.co/edit/GnMe83xGDF4pWxUzQz79?p=preview

Comment: b bac wth feedback...much thanks.....

Comment: Is this example solve yours  issue?

Comment: nw i can load the map but i cant put a marker for searche location when i open the map,the issue nw is when i open a link of map i cant submit the object containing latitude and longitude,since th function call is private,

Comment: you can pass {{item.lat}} and {{item.lng}} form $state to the next view and assign marker like 

<marker position="{{item.lat}}, {{item.lng}}"></marker>

Comment: Simple example if u don't mind,I try but it is not working